# Compare two files and store unique data in a new file in Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.8

I have two files where data are stored in a pattern. Here are the details:

file1.txt:

```
1.1.1.1 -> 0.0.0.0
2.2.2.2 -> 0.0.0.0
3.3.3.3 -> 1.1.1.1
4.4.4.4 -> 2.2.2.2
```

pattern of file1.txt is like this:

```
source ip -> destination ip
```

file2.txt:

```
5.5.5.5
6.6.6.6
2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1
```

pattern of file2.txt is something like this:

```
source ip
```

test.py:

```
with open("file1.txt") as fp1, open("file2.txt") as fp2, open("newfile.txt", "w") as fp3:
    i = 0
    k = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if i == 0:
                # at first get line from both file
                l1 = next(fp1)
                l2 = next(fp2)
            # if both the line is equal get another line
            if l1 == l2:
                try:
                    l1 = next(fp1)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                l2 = next(fp2)
            # if line are not equal then put l1 in new file
            else:
                fp3.write(l1)
                try:
                    l1 = next(fp1)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
            i += 1
        except StopIteration:
            k += 1
            if k == 2:
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break
```

My code doesn't comparing these both files. he is just storing file1.txt data in a new file which is file3.txt. Compare just source ip's of both files and store data in a new file. The stored data should be like this. File1.txt always compare with file2.txt. if file1.txt data doesn't exist in file2.txt, that data should be store in a new file which is file3.txt. I have shown my output below:

file3.txt:

```
3.3.3.3 -> 1.1.1.1
4.4.4.4 -> 2.2.2.2
```

The common data shouldn't be store in a new file. Compare the two files and if both of them common data, that common data will be ignored and unique data will be stored in a new file.

Comment: you haven't asked any question

Comment: Dear, @Sembei Normaki, I have asked a question that compare these both files and file1.txt data and file2.txt common data should be ignored and file1.txt unique data should be stored in a new file

Comment: you can do this by writing some code. Then you can post your code if it gives you any error or you get stuck in some specific part and we will try to help. Just make some code that reads file1 and file2 does the comparisons you mentioned and writes the results to file3. Is the problem you are getting about how to do the comparisons?

Comment: I didn't put any negative mark in your question. But if the question lacks any show of effort it might get closed and/or downvoted

Comment: dear @SembeiNorimaki I have updated my question with my python code. Kindly have an eye on it

Comment: First read `file2` into a set. Then iterate over file1 line by line, split into origin_ip and destinatio_ip, then check if the origin_ip exist in the set, if not, write the whle line into file3.

Comment: @kindly update my code as your instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need some regex knowledge.

```
import re

input1 = open("file1.txt","r")
input2 = open("file2.txt","r")

output = open("output.txt","w")


file2_data = input2.read()


for line in input1:
    regex_search = re.search(r"\d.\d.\d.\d", line)
    source_ip = regex_search[0]
    if re.search(source_ip,file2_data)==None:
        output.write(line)
```